# VSCode C++ feature `Go To References` is broken after upgrade to V1.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was prompted to upgrade the C++ extension in VSCode from v0.29 to 1.0.0.

Now my `Go to References` feature is no longer working on my C++ project.  It shows:

`No References Found for <symbol>`

Here are my code levels:

```
Version: 1.49.0
Commit: e790b931385d72cf5669fcefc51cdf65990efa5d
Date: 2020-09-10T17:39:53.251Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

The OUTPUT console for C/C++ shows:

```
Warning] Some references may be missing, because workspace parsing was incomplete when Find All References was started.

Quick info operation failed: FE: 'Compiler exited with error - No IL available'
Quick info operation failed: FE: 'Compiler exited with error - No IL available'
```

The OUTPUT console for C/C++ Diag shows:

```
-------- Diagnostics - 9/15/2020, 12:16:58 PM
Version: 1.0.0
Current Configuration:
{
    "name": "Mac",
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
    ],
    "defines": [],
    "macFrameworkPath": [
        "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
    ],
    "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/cmake",
    "cStandard": "c11",
    "cppStandard": "c++17",
    "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
    "browse": {
        "path": [
            "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
    },
    "compilerArgs": []
}
Translation Unit Mappings:
<removed>

Translation Unit Configurations:
<removed>

------- Workspace parsing diagnostics -------
Number of folders and files enumerated: 39906
Number of files discovered (not excluded): 34663
Number of files parsed: 2561

------- Potential include path issues --------
Some headers exist in multiple locations. If IntelliSense is behaving incorrectly,
try adding one of the alternate paths to the "includePath" in your configuration in
c_cpp_properties.json to override the automatic path discovery for that header.

<removed>
```

Note: I removed the files for my project.

I did try various compilers, i.e. clang, g++, gcc, and cmake.  My project does does use cmake.

The `Potential Include Path Issues` doesn't make sense to me.  I have the `includePath` listed above.

So why cannot it find the correct header files in my project?

Why else might the `Go To References` feature be broken?

I am aware the changeLog shows `Potentially Breaking Changes` and other interesting comments on this level.  But how do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was better to open this in Stack Overflow or as a Github issue.  Please advise if Github is a better place for this. Or both?

Answer (score 1):

I got same issues after updating the version to v1.0.0 too. And I found an open issuse in github(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6147), it hasn't been solved yet.

I just removed all path in includePath except "${default}", the VSCode can find and jump to  symbols only defined in the workspace at least now.

Let's wait for the resolution from github.